# Clicking on one Element(Button) out of Elements with similiar Class Names on an Html document

Tags: html, internet-explorer, vbscript, automation

I am a beginner working on a VBScript. There are four classes in an html page with similar names:

```
<a title="Like" class="icon-like" href="#" data-action="AnswerLikeToggle" />
<a title="Like" class="icon-like active" href="#" data-action="AnswerLikeToggle" />
<a title="Like" class="icon-like vote" style="display: none;" href="#" data-action="PhotopollVote" />
<div class="rating icon-like" style="margin-bottom: 337px;">79%</div> />
```

I am using the following code to click on 20 Elements(buttons) of the class="icon-like" using following variable "counter" as an index value:

```
Dim currentlike, counter

'START FOR LOOP TO CLICK ON 20 BUTTONS
wscript.sleep(1000)

For counter = 0 To 20
wscript.sleep(1200)

Set currentlike = webbrowser.Document.GetElementsByClassName("icon-like")(counter)
currentlike.Click

Next
```

But there is a problem with this code. I only want the script to click on the elements of the class="icon-like" but this code collects all the elements of the other three classnames("icon-like active", "rating icon-like", "icon-like vote") too and also clicks on them because all those classes also have the string "icon-like" in their names. I have tried lots of different things but cant seem to get only the elements of that one class (class="icon-like"). The other attributes also are similar and difficult to use. Can someone propose a solution to this in VBScript?

Help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: You could check if the element has multiple classes using `If Ubound(split(currentlike.ClassName," ")) = 0 Then` ,or you could check if there is a space in `currentlike.ClassName` like `If InStr(currentlike.ClassName," ")=0 Then` ...

Comment: Try to store text 'icon-like' in string variable and try to match it with the value of 'webbrowser.Document.GetElementsByClassName()' using IF condition will help you to find exact match of 'icon-like' class. If class does not has this exact value then IF condition will get false.